# Getting wrong width for thickness of element in Revit using Revit API

Tags: python, revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

I created a plugin with PyRevit using Revit API to get the materials in a layer used in the model with their thickness, but the result coming from API is not the same result that I gave to materials as thickness.

For instance I tried this code:

```
# Create the dict for JSON
components = {
    "wall": [],
}

# Select all walls
walls = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).ToElements()

# Get the outer wall
outer_wall = None
for item in walls:
    if isinstance(item, Wall):
        el = doc.GetElement(item.Id)
        if el.Name == "Aussenwand":
            outer_wall = doc.GetElement(el.Id)


# Get the material and width of each layer of outer wall and add to components
if outer_wall is not None:
    wall_type = doc.GetElement(outer_wall.GetTypeId())
    compound_structure = wall_type.GetCompoundStructure()
    for layer_index in range(compound_structure.LayerCount):
        layer_width = compound_structure.GetLayerWidth(layer_index)
        material_id = compound_structure.GetMaterialId(layer_index)
        if material_id.IntegerValue != -1:
            material = doc.GetElement(material_id)
            components["wall"].append({material.MaterialCategory: layer_width})
```

so here is for example the result of this code:

```
{
'wall':
 [{'Gipsputz': 0.049212598425196846},
 {'Mauerwerk': 0.5741469816272966},
 {'Isolierung': 0.45931758530183725},
 {'Gipsputz': 0.049212598425196846}]
}
```

But the thickness that I gave to this material in Revit is something else, for example the first element should have the thcikness of 15 mm
[This is the layers of wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LyMJ.png)

I thick that there is maybe some default thickness for the materials and Revit is getting them.
Is there anyone who has any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

After hours of conflict with this code, I realized there is a mistake from my side. The Revit API is giving me units in imperial system and I need to change them to metric.

There are 2 solutions for that, I chose to do it using Revit API with **UnitTypeId** and **UnitUtils**:

```
# Get the material and width of each layer of outer wall and add to components

if outer_wall is not None:
    wall_type = doc.GetElement(outer_wall.GetTypeId())
    compound_structure = wall_type.GetCompoundStructure()
    for layer_index in range(compound_structure.LayerCount):
        layer_width_feet = compound_structure.GetLayerWidth(layer_index)
        layer_width_mm = UnitUtils.ConvertFromInternalUnits(layer_width_feet, UnitTypeId.Millimeters)
        material_id = compound_structure.GetMaterialId(layer_index)
        material = doc.GetElement(material_id)
        components["wall"].append({material.MaterialCategory: round(layer_width_mm)})
```

The other solution is to change it simply by code and not using Revit API. Fore example each 1 foot is 304,8 mm.

Comment: I strongly recommend using the Revit API, and simply always being aware that all length values are indeed stored in imperial units:

Comment: Cf. [Internal Imperial Units](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/03/internal-imperial-units.html) and [Imperial Internal Revit Database Length Units](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/06/getting-started-creating-families-and-rfa-files.html).